# Is it vedanta that reconciled all the religions(ways) in Bharat during dwapara and thretha yuga?

Tags: scripture, vedanta, dwapara-yuga, treta-yuga

In Mahabharata and Ramayana, we can find wide variety of traditions, rituals. Each one was encouraged. We can see the shaktism, Shaivism, Vaishnavism, Saura etc.,

So, we can say that there are multiple ways in Hinduism before Kali yuga.

My doubt is that how did all the branches got reconciliation during Dwapara and Tretha yugas and people lived without any discrepancies between branches? Which inherent quality of Sanathana dharma did it? Is it Vedantha satra or any other central agency like king?

Comment: I suggest that a Wikipedia article on Hinduism written by a non- Hindu Westerner is not a valid source on Hinduism. You are further confusing the modern popular usage of the word Hindu with the philosophical and religious traditions of Vedanta. You might like reading http://consciouslivingfoundation.org/ebooks/13/CLF-HistoryOfIndianPhilosophy.pdf and https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Question remains same even if i remove the quote.

Comment: My opinion is shavism,vaishnavism etc., did not exist under the **vaidika matham** . Meaning either only one of them or none of them are true as per veda/vedanta. Now in kali yuga we have all these sects or some other sects sprung within vaidika matham deluding us. If I'm correct pashupata matham did exist even in previous yugas. So there exist some vedanta independent school of thought in previous yugas too.Also other thing is only puranas have such sectarian attitude but now we have vaishnava upanishads,saiva upanishads etc., deluding us!! So I don't think vedanta in general reconciled them.

Comment: **My opinion is shavism,vaishnavism etc., did not exist under the vaidika matham**. Is it an opinion from scriptures or otherwise? @Satya

Comment: They certainly exist under sanatana dharma. But as far as vaidika matham is considered I don't think all sects can be under vaidika matham. Only one or none can be true. All deities are equally glorified in veda samhitas. **But the presence of classification of upanishads in muktika itself shows vedanta did not reconcile them.**

Comment: According SriMadvacharya, all the branches of vedanta all the matham exists at all time just vaidika matham(who believe in Vedic authority) Because Krishna says clearly about vaishnavism means there are other shaivism, pasupatha, jainisim and Kaplika matham was there you can have reference Srimad Bhagavatham about Kaplika trying to kill Bharata.. So all matham do exists at all times there is no reconciliation. @Satya

Comment: @Prasanna R. Agreed. Puranas too hints at this. Whenever a praise of Shiva comes there's also glorification of pashupata matham. I'm taking back my statements like classification of upanishads etc., But I never said only one sampradaya existed once. My point is only one of them could be true,that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Who says that the branches got reconciled and people lived without any discrepancies between branches? Actually they never got reconciled and Hindu people have always lived with discrepancies between branches just like they live today with various branches Shaiva, Shakta, Vaishnava, Saura, etc.

The purpose of Vedanta is not necessary to reconcile those ways or branches but to teach us what of all those teachings is the ultimate and correct and which is not, so that we do not stay to be an ignorant in this world as to what is the ultimate purpose of all Vedic knowledge. As Lord Krishna says in the Bhagavad-gita 15.15, a scripture which is said to be one of the pillars the Vedanta is based upon, namely *prasthana trayi*:

> vedaiś ca sarvair aham eva vedyo    vedānta-kṛd veda-vid eva cāham
>
> **By all the Vedas, I am to be known.** Indeed, **I am the compiler of
> Vedānta**, and **I am the knower of the Vedas**.

That's the purpose of the Vedanta, to direct us to the conclusion, to the final aim, and not necessary to reconcile branches. For that reason we have Vedanta. Teaching of Vedanta is crucial to enable us to properly understand and properly interpret Vedic texts and the teachings contained in them. Every Hindu who is serious about adhering to Hindu teaching should properly learn at least the basics of Vedanta teaching. Without learning Vedanta one will most likely remain to be just one ignorant Hindu in this world, one who has missed the wisdom, without been able to understand the aim and substance of the Vedic texts.

Comment: Please provide reference for your first paragraph.

Comment: @hanugm I don't have it. But I think you don't need it for it is obvious from the scriptures themselves, as you yourself mentioned, namely Itihasas, Puranas, etc, that they have various ways Shaiva, Shakta, Vaishnava, Saura, etc. All of them would not have existed in case only one of them should have existed. I think from that fact we can conclude that it was not originally intended for them to be reconciled, but original intention of Vedic authorities, gods and sages who composed all those scriptures with all those varieties of branches was to give to the people all those various branches.

Comment: But if you see Ramayana and other scriptures, they do mention that there are no problems between citizens in kingdoms and all are in peace...

Comment: @hanugm Well, that is exactly the purpose of Hindu dharma, everyone to go their own way, ... in peace.